# Docker-compose volume doesn't save state of container for Keycloak

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, keycloak, docker-volume

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  idprovider-app:
    container_name: idprovider-app
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
        - keycloak-data-volume:/var/lib/keycloak/data
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"   
      - "8443:8443"     
volumes:
  keycloak-data-volume:
    external: true
```

dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:7.0.1
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443
```

**docker inspect "container"**

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "keycloak-data-volume",
                "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/keycloak-data-volume/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/keycloak/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
```

**docker volume inspect keycloak-data-volume**

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-12-10T19:31:55Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/keycloak-data-volume/_data",
        "Name": "keycloak-data-volume",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

There isn't errors, but it doesn't save state. I have no any idea what's wrong. I run it on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

Using default database location you may try this option with docker-compose:

```
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:14.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .local/keycloak/:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/
```

Found similar answer with plain docker https://stackoverflow.com/a/60554189/6916890

`docker run --volume /root/keycloak/data/:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/`

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using docker setup mentioned in https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker and looking for a way to persist data even if the container is killed then you can use docker volumes and mount the `/opt/keycloak/data/` folder from docker container to a directory in your local machine.

The only change you need to do in the docker command mentioned in the getting started doc is add volume mount docker option using

`-v /<path-in-your-local-machine>/keycloak-data/:/opt/keycloak/data/`

so, the final docker run command with an example of local directory would look like:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \ 
-v /Users/amit/workspace/keycloak/keycloak-data/:/opt/keycloak/data/ \
quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.3 start-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents, worked for me with the persistent volume pointing to /opt/keycloak/data/h2, with Keycloak docker version 19.0.1 :

```
-v /<path-in-your-local-machine>/keycloak-data/:/opt/keycloak/data/h2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for version >= 17.0**

To complement lazylead's answer, you need to use `/opt/keycloak/data/` instead of `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/` for keycloak version >= 17.0.0

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60554189/5424025

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using with it? I think you need to bind the database volume as well with it to save the state.

For eg: for postgress

```
services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

or for mysql

```
services:
  mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use another one service for postgres? Can I run postgres inside idprovider-app? For standalone keycloak I can set configuration in standalone.xml to use postgres, can I do something like that in docker?

Comment: I am sorry I am not very much familiar with Keycloak and its configurations. I pointed out those because I thought the state are saved inside db that's why I suggested  to map db volume as well. Also in their [github repo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/master/docker-compose-examples). they are mentioning about it.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the source of the database in the environment variables. 
If you used a different service for the PostgreSQL instance for postgres, you must specify the DB_ADDR environment variable in your service.

```
services:
  idprovider-app:
    container_name: idprovider-app
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      # Specify hostname of the database (eg: hostname or hostname:port)
      DB_ADDR: hostname:5432 
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
        - keycloak-data-volume:/var/lib/keycloak/data
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"   
      - "8443:8443"     
volumes:
  keycloak-data-volume:
    external: true
```

Comment: I think this example is incomplete.