# How to take db backup in keycloak docker container

Tags: java, django, database, docker, keycloak

I installed keycloak using docker for my `django` project

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
```

now everything is working fine but now i want take backup of keycloak db in docker but i do not know which database installed by default inside keycloak docker container,so how to take backup and restore data,
 i was using `$ sudo docker exec -it 35ba690a68fd /bin/bash` this command to interact with container, please any suggestion. i am using redhat Linux

Comment: `Database` section of this image [`docs`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) might be helpful...

Answer (score 24):

### Keycloak < 17.0.0:

the default database is located in `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/` the name is `keycloak.mv.db`

if you want to back it up, I suggest mapping a volume when running keycloak:

```
docker run --volume /root/keycloak/data/:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/ ...
```

this way the database will stay on the host and will keep the changes even if you destroy the container and recreate it.

### For Keycloak >= 17.0.0:

the default database is located in `/opt/keycloak/data/h2/` the name is `keycloakdb.mv.db`

if you want to back it up, map the following volume when running keycloak:

```
docker run --volume /root/keycloak/data/:/opt/keycloak/data/h2/ ...
```

The whole `data` folder could also be used (instead of `h2`).

Comment: Keycloak container is failing with the following exception: `IllegalStateException: WFLYSRV0126: Could not create server content directory: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/content`

Comment: try running it first without the volume so it creates everything, then map it. also check permissions on the local directory you are mapping

Comment: Could you please advise what should be the the permissions?

Comment: I think the data folder has to be writable by user "jboss". but you could try making it world writable first, to make sure the issue is coming from there.

Comment: For Keycloak 17.0.0 the path is:
`/opt/keycloak/data/`
So the mapping is then:
`--volume /root/keycloak/data/:/opt/keycloak/data/`
Or (in my case) in Windows:
`--volume c:/keycloak/data:/opt/keycloak/data`

Answer (score 1):

By default, Keycloak is using its embedded H2 database. I suggest that you move to an external DB so that you will be able to managed backup more simply.

see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_database and https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/master/server#database regarding the supported DB and how to setup env variables to connect to the DB from the Keycloak container.

Regards,